# how to make some specific widths and heights and some auto with jframes - Java

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, border-layout

I wanna make a `jframe` that looks something like this:

[image]

As shown on image, I wanna have right side panel to have width of 200px and bottom panel height of 80px, then everything else to be auto, as I want the window to be resizable.

Could someone please help me to achieve this? I've been trying with `gridLayout`, `BorderLayout` and others. I've seen something with insets, but can't figure it out.

Comment: You might be better off with [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) or [FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/).

Comment: Thanks :D I'm gonna try and play around with MigLayout and figure out if i can manage to achieve this. If someone else would achieve this before me, you are welcome to post the results here! :)

Comment: Please feel free to search this site for your solution as I'm sure that this or similar questions have been asked many times previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        JPanel centerWrapper = new JPanel();        

        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        right.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 10));

        centerWrapper.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        centerWrapper.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerWrapper.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();        
        bottom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 200));
        bottom.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(centerWrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // you can now use center, right and bottom

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```